# nokogiri gem install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I've searched and found some people getting various issues while trying to install nokogiri but I haven't seen anyone with this many or these types of files being skipped....any ideas?

```
gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.0
unable to convert "\xE4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0/doc/examples/testWriter.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xF8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0/entities.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0/runtest.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0/test/XInclude/ents/isolatin.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xF8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/libxml2-2.8.0/testapi.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xF6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26/libxslt-1.1.26/ChangeLog, skipping
unable to convert "\xF6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26/libxslt-1.1.26/libxslt/xslt.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xE1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26/libxslt-1.1.26/NEWS, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26/libxslt-1.1.26/tests/xmlspec/logo-REC, skipping
unable to convert "\xFD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/nokogiri/tmp/i686-apple-darwin11/ports/libxslt/1.1.26/libxslt-1.1.26/win32/Readme.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/bin/xmlcatalog, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/bin/xmllint, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ports/i686-apple-darwin11/libxslt/1.1.26/bin/xsltproc, skipping
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the errors are test or example code, and all the errors are related to encoding, when it try con convert a character to UTF-8 if found an error it skip it, but isn't very important, nokogiri will work after those warnings

Comment: If someone down voted, please, write a comment, I like to know your opinion :D

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in `rdoc 4.0.0`. Try to upgrade to the version `4.0.1`.

What worked for me, it was to disable `rdoc` and reinstall.

Using the command `gem update`, it seems not to work due to the same parsing error (?).

```
$ ruby --disable-gems -S "Rdoc"
gem install rdoc
```

Comment: Upgrading rdoc did it for me.